# Permutation of a value by another

Tags: r, statistics, permutation, glm

I am working in R with a database that has these two variables. Camouflage and Detection. The values are binary, 0 for being conspicuous and 1 for being camouflaged. 1 for detected and 0 for undetected. However, during my analysis I added values that are called Unknown in the Detection variable. I would like to permute the Unknown with 1 then 0 and see if each of the permutations affects the significance of the glm that I am using. The permutation may be that all Unknown change to 0 or to 1, or that some change to 1 and others to 0. A random permutation. It may be simple, it's just that I am not really functional with R.

Comment: it's a lot easier to follow a question if you give examples of what you have, the desired output and what you've tried

Comment: I actually have two columns in a database: Detection and Camouflage. I want to see whether the model when it is camouflaged is being detected or not. However, sometimes it was not clear if it was detected so I put Unknown in the Detection column. I want to use this Unknown to see what kind of results would I have if the Unknown was actually detected (1) or not detected (0). I hope I was clear

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
camouf = c(1,NA,0,0,1,0,NA,NA,NA,0,1)

perm <- function(vec, chance = 0.5){
    unknown <- which(is.na(camouf))
    vec[unknown] <- sample(0:1, size=length(unknown), 
                       prob = c(1-chance,chance), replace = TRUE)
    return(vec)
}

perm(camouf) # do it once

replicate(50, perm(camouf))  # do it many times
```

It defines a function `perm` to do what you call permute to a vector of `0` and `1` and put in a random `0` or `1` at the places, where the original had an `NA`. The probability of a `1` can be given via the `chance =` argument.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I actually have the values in a column in a database. Should I be transforming it into a vector? And I do not have NA, it is actually Unknown so I guess in the first operation I should replace NA with Unknown right?

Comment: A column in R is always one kind of data. if some lines are of type character, like "Unknown", then the other values in that column cannot be numeric but must bi of type character, too. `NA` for "not available" is a special value in R that can be part of an all-numeric column. So when reading the data into R you must make shure, that all "Unknown"-values become NA. After reading the data into R, they form a `data.frame` and every column in a `data.frame` is a vector. This is why I demonstrated how to do it with a vector.

Comment: Okay now I understand. In fact, R was changing my Unknown value to 3 whenever I transformed my column into a vector. Once I perform this permutation, how can I check the effect of each permutation on my glm which is `model1=glm(Detection~Camouflage, data,family=binomial)` ?

Comment: You could compute the glm for each of the newly constructed vectors and then compare the models/coefficients/... . It all depends on why you tried to do this in the first place. I suppose you try to do some kind of bootstrapping but you never stated, what you want to reach with this.

Comment: Yes it is some kind of bootstrapping but I do not know how to do it. My purpose is to replace the unknown values or the NA with all the possible combinations of 0/1 in order to see if the effect of camouflage on detection is maintained significative or not. Actually, I am analyzing camera traps and in some cases it is not clear if the predator detects the model so I just put Unknown. I realized a glm without considering the Unknown and got a significative of effect of camouflage on detection. Now, I want to see if it is maintained if the Unknown was actually detected or not.